# MySQLdb - Parameterized Queries without cursor?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using [MySQLdb](https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/user_guide.html?highlight=parameter#mysqldb) for Python 3.6 to store some data in a database. I have avoided using cursors as per [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6998585/cursors-on-mysql-good-or-bad) to avoid the performance hit. However, I am not seeing a good way to [parameterize my data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/775296/mysql-parameterized-queries) unless I use a cursor.

My question is: is there a way to parameterize data on a set based operation, or do I need to choose between using a cursor vs. sanitizing my own data?

Comment: I think that's confusing two types of cursor. One is to iterate through result sets, the other is just as a type of connection. Using cursors to arbitrarily rather than sequentially step through result sets is where you have trouble. The slow cursor is [`CURSOR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html).

Comment: I appreciate that! Sounds like I need to broaden my knowledge of SQL a little! I'll do some looking. Sounds like I'm safe to use the cursor for my query at least!